# Disable top speaker on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiosession, speaker

In my app, I use the default speaker (at the bottom of the phone) to play music and the top-front microphone to record user voice. Before iPhone7, I was glad with this, because the top-front microphone did not record (too much) the speakers output.

Now with iPhone 7, the music is played on the new top-front speaker (on addition to bottom one), close to the microphone. So that the music is recorded loudly, with a terrible result.

Is there a way to programatically disable this top speaker?

Comment: Or maybe should I work with balance depending the orientation ? I would find it crappy...

Comment: Anything about this? My issue is still unresolved. Anyone?